# How do I manage context when exposing object methods in JS modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Okay, I realize this can be considered subjective, but I'm trying to better understand how to consider scope when writing modules that only expose what's needed publicly.  I have a string utility that I've written as an object literal below:

```
const substrings = {
  query: {},
  text: "",
  results: [],

  exists: function (index) {
    const exists = index >= 0

    return exists
  },

  check: function () {
    const q = this.query
    const start = q.openIndex
    const stop = q.closeIndex

    if (q.hasOpen && !q.hasClose) {
      console.log("Missing closing delimiter.")
    }
    if (!q.hasOpen && q.hasClose) {
      console.log("Missing opening delimiter.")
    }
    if (q.hasOpen && q.hasClose && start > stop) {
      console.log("Closing delimiter found before opening.")
    }
    if (!q.hasOpen && !q.hasClose && this.results.length == 0) {
      console.log("No results found.")
    }

    const order = start < stop
    const check = q.hasOpen && q.hasClose && order

    return check
  },

  update: function () {
    const q = this.query
    const text = this.text

    q.before = this.text.indexOf(q.open)
    q.start = q.before + q.open.length

    this.text = text.slice(q.start, text.length)

    q.stop = this.text.indexOf(q.close)
    q.after = q.stop + q.close.length
    q.openIndex = q.before
    q.closeIndex = q.before + q.stop
    q.hasOpen = this.exists(q.openIndex)
    q.hasClose = this.exists(q.stop)

    const newPosition = q.start + q.after

    q.position = q.position + newPosition

    this.query = q
  },

  substrings: function () {
    const q = this.query

    const current = this.text.slice(0, q.stop)
    const fullLength = this.text.length

    this.text = this.text.slice(q.after, fullLength)

    this.results.push(current)

    this.update()

    if (this.check()) {
      this.substrings()
    }
  },

  init: function (open, close, text) {
    this.results = []
    this.query = {
      open,
      close,
      position: 0,
    }

    this.text = text
    this.update()
  },

  getSubstrings: function (open, close, text) {
    this.init(open, close, text)

    if (this.check()) {
      this.substrings()
      return this.results
    }
  },

  getSubstring: function (open, close, text) {
    this.init(open, close, text)

    if (this.check()) {
      return this.text.slice(0, this.query.stop)
    }
  }

}
```

I want to use it as a Node module and expose the `getSubstring` and `getSubstrings` methods, but if I were to do:

```
module.exports = {
  all: substrings.getSubstrings,
  one: substrings.getSubstring
}
```

I would get an error due to the usage of `this`.  I realize that if I replace `this` with the object var name `substrings` to reference it directly, it works.  I could also refactor it to be one big function or smaller functions and just export the 2 I need.

I am trying to go about learning things the right way and am struggling with how I should be thinking about context. I understand how `this` changes here, but I feel like I'm not fully wrapping my head around how I should consider context when structuring my code.

Is there a more elegant solution to expose methods with code like this that wasn't written to separate private and public methods?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to `bind` the exported functions to the proper calling context inside the `exports` object:

```
module.exports = {
  all: substrings.getSubstrings.bind(substrings),
  one: substrings.getSubstring.bind(substrings)
}
```

Personally, I prefer using the revealing module pattern over object literals for situations like this. With the revealing module pattern, create an IIFE that returns the desired functions, referring to *local variables* instead of properties on `this`. For example:

```
const { getSubstrings, getSubstring } = (() => {
  let query = {}
  let text = ''
  let results = []
  function exists(index) {
    return index >= 0
  }
  function check() {
    const q = query;
    // ...
  }
  ...
  function getSubstrings(open, close, text) {
  }
  ...
  return { getSubstrings, getSubstring };
})();

module.exports = {
  all: getSubstrings,
  one: getSubstring
}
```

This is somewhat opinion-based, but code can be easier to read when there aren't any `this` references to worry about.

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning and wanted to know I wasn't missing something I should know.  I had tried using `bind` and understand how it should be used since I had arguments, but I must not have been using it correctly.

Comment: I will read more on the revealing module pattern. I am trying to learn more about choosing which way to structure things best.  I was satisfied with the object literal flexibility and thought I had a good understanding of the context and was frustrated when it didn't work as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: I would upvote the answer but I don't have the rep ;0

Comment: You can still mark answers as Accepted if they solve the problem you're having :)